# Wordpress upload server loacated image file to media library via php file without form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, upload

I have an image file on a server (for example: images/flower.jpg).
I want to add this file to media library via a php file.

I researched on the net a lot and found the code below. This code requires an html form to upload into media library. I must select files and click the upload button. What i would like to do instead, is give a file name to be uploaded in a php file, not using an html form.

```html
<?php 
include "../wp-config.php";
 ?>
 <form id="file_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" multiple="multiple">
     <input name="my_file_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?

 require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
 require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
 require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $files = $_FILES["my_file_upload"];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("upload_file" => $file);
            $attachment_id = media_handle_upload("upload_file", 0);

            if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                // There was an error uploading the image.
                echo "Error adding file";
            } else {
                // The image was uploaded successfully!
                echo "File added successfully with ID: " . $attachment_id . "<br>";
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, array(800, 600)) . "<br>"; //Display the uploaded image with a size you wish. In this case it is 800x600
            }
        }
    }
} 


?>
```

Comment: Please edit to include any steps you have taken so far to fix the issue yourself.

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I found soution on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256830/programmatically-adding-images-to-media-library/288244#288244